# Is there a way to get Koppen climate of a location?

Tags: python

Is there a simple way in Python that would give me the Koppen climate of a site by its coordinates (for example latitude and longitude)?

Something like

```
>>> koppen(lat = 40, lat = -3) 
'Csa'
```

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same question and luckily came accross this link:
http://hanschen.org/koppen/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This is a late response, but here is a solution in case anyone stumbles across this question in the future.

An API exists that will return the classification code if you submit latitude and longitude location.

https://rapidapi.com/aptitudeapps/api/koppen-climate-classification/

Comment: All your answers are promoting rapidapi. I'd respectfully ask you to stop, otherwise you could justifiably end up being treated as a spammer. Thanks.

Comment: People are presenting a problem, and I proposed a solution...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33406154)